# Why wikijs didn't assign user with google self registration?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose with wikijs 2.5.201 and postgresql 13

I have an error when a user login with automatic registration. 
I set up google oath in my wiki properly, 1:1 with wikijs docx. 
When user is not in database, then wiki create wikijs profile for him, but it didn't assign him to group which i specified in "sefl registration" section.

i got errors only in postgresql:

```
[48] ERROR:  insert or update on table "userGroups" violates foreign key constraint "usergroups_groupid_foreign"

[48] DETAIL:  Key (groupId)=(3) is not present in table "groups".

[48] STATEMENT:  insert into "userGroups" ("groupId", "userId") values ($1, $2), ($3, $4) returning "groupId"
```

Comment: Can you verify that a group with `groupId = 3` is present in the table groups?

Comment: @Ftisiot is not present and alsa i cannot greate group with id=3. I tryed manualy do pg_dump and changes id to 3 but i didn't work out. Also i tryed to change group which new google users will be assign to, but that didn't worked to. Currently i don't know why somehow assign to gruopid=3 stucked and i cannot changed it anyway.